# Timeout including time in queue JCL Z os IBM

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I need to set a Timeout, in a JCL step that calls a Unix script through bpxbtach. I did it with

```
//STEPX EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH, PARM='sh /x.sh',TIME=(,10)
```

However, After some time I realized that does not include the time in the queue. they say " This run time refers to actual execution time only, and does not include the time that the job spends in the INPUT or INPUT HOLD queues" https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/rd60/cbwjto.htm

That is microfocus JCL, but I verified the behavior is that on IBM Z too.

So even if I set the timeout to 10 seconds, the step can take several minutes if the queue is attending other things. I need a timeout that kills the step no matter the reason it took so long.  I haven't been able to find what I need. Please help.

Comment: Why are you trying do do this?  Jobs are, by definition, batch work. If you need something to complete in 10 seconds, you need to take other steps.  You’re also conflating job steps and jobs.  I’d suggest asking a question describing what youre

Comment: I think this is an 'XY' problem - you're trying to solve problem 'X' when you actually need to solve problem 'Y'  In over 30 years on mainframes I've never seen a requirement to cancel a batch job if it hasn't run within 10 seconds of being run. Batch jobs are not time dependent to this degree. Now you might have a need to run a script within 10s of some event occurring, so I'd ask your system programmers if you have an automation package like Ops/MVS, AF/Operator or IBM's System Automation.

Comment: the 10 seconds and that line of code was just for the sake of example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

z/OS batch really isn't the best choice for time-critical work. As you figured out, the JCL "TIME" parameter is about CPU time consumption, not an elapsed time control. If this is a business-critical need, then by all means talk to your z/OS administrators - they can certainly configure your system such that your job is very likely to run without delay, but this isn't usually default behavior.

You don't provide a lot of detail as to what else your job might be doing and how it gets submitted. If you have the ability to control how your job is submitted, one option might be to spawn your shell script directly rather than submitting a batch process to run your script.

For example, what you've described is submitting JCL that spawns BPXBATCH, then BPXBATCH spawns your shell script. Instead, you might write a small C program that simply calls "spawn()" to run the shell as a distinct UNIX process - that's not difficult, depending on how you're submitting the JCL you shared. You cut out the need for the batch job - just run your script directly.

If you're running in a TSO environment, the OSHELL command lets you interactively run your script. You can even automate the whole process with a simple REXX script, and none of this requires a pass through a batch initiator.

If your site runs SSH or similar, you might consider launching your script through an SSH command - this even works across a network. SSH lets you launch a shell session and pass a command for execution...again, there's no JCL or input queue here.

If your administrators would allow it, another alternative would be to run your JCL via a "START" command. Unlike batch JCL, when a START command is encountered, the work you're starting runs immediately - there's no input queue for started tasks. Start commands can be issued from JCL too, and since they're issued as the JCL is scanned and not when the job starts, these are fairly immediate too.

Inside your shell script, it's pretty easy to setup an elapsed time limit - there are examples [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/sigalrm-timers-and-stdin-analysis).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply, I believe the right answer is simply not using JCL for time critical tasks, however, in this case and some others, for almost political reasons it needs to be JCL and bpxbatch is the only thing that can communicate with unix, oshell can't be started much less ssh.  With the privilages I have, START seemed to work. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems in your code...

```
//STEPX EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH, PARM='sh /x.sh',TIME=(,10)
```

First, you have a space between `BPXBATCH,` and `PARM=` which will not execute your shell script and may result in a JCL error.

Second, you are using the `TIME` parameter of the EXEC statement, which limits *CPU* time, yet you reference a desire to cancel the job step if it waits more than some amount of time in the input queue, which is a *clock* time limitation.

There is no way to cancel the job from the job itself via JCL parameters based on clock time, either including or excluding time spent in the input queue.

If you really need to do this, I suggest you look into capabilities of your shop's job scheduler package.  You might want to reexamine *why* you need to cancel a job if it doesn't run to completion within 10 clock seconds after you submit it.